# How to write into a json file in Android

Tags: android, json, file-io

I am using a bundled json file in my application. I want to read and write data into the json file. I have a listview which displays the currently available data in json and an edittext into which user enters data. That data has to be written into the json. How to do this?

This is my code...

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        String myjsonstring;

         ArrayList<Data> web = new ArrayList<Data>();

         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            JsonParser();

            }



        private void JsonParser() 
        {
            // Reading text file from assets folder
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                        "single.json")));
                String temp;
                while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(temp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close(); // stop reading
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            myjsonstring = sb.toString();

            // Try to parse JSON
            try {


                JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("message");

                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Getting data from individual JSONObject

                    Data data = new Data(jsonObj.getString("name") , jsonObj.getString("msg"));

                    web.add(data);
                }

                final customtest1 adapter = new customtest1(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_single,web); 
                final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TEST.........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                });
              //Send activity......

                final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
                final Button imb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
                imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) 
                 { 
                      String str = et.getText().toString();

                      Data store = new Data(et.getText().toString());
                      web.add(store);

                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You entered...."+store, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      et.setText(" ");
                      scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                //Screen auto scrollup....
                 private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
                        list.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                                list.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
                            }
                        });
                }});

            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot edit files added as resources, make a copy of it in your application data folder

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you could parse the jsonarray from the exist file,then add the new data to the old jasonarray,then write the new data to the exist file.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot edit file in asset folder at runtime .load file into memory and then try this method to write to internal memory :

```
private void writeToFile(String jsonData) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("single.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write(jsonData);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
} 
}
```

Comment: Which data is being written into this file ?How to pass the data ?

Comment: this is to write on internal memory. you cn not change file in asset folder at runtime.read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637576/write-to-file-json-into-assets-folder-android

Comment: oh ok.so when i am using a json url in real time,i can do that but not to the json file in assets folder right ?

Comment: new problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933195/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-url-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50749/discussion-between-nevaeh-and-wqrahd)