# How to display an image from a url in a ListView in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, url

I am using json parsing in my application.I have a `ListView` which displays some data and also an `ImageView`.Here i want to display an image from another url in an `ImageView`.How to do this ?

**This is my code...**

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String url = "http://myurl/json/main.json";

// JSON Node names

private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_VIEWERS = "viewers";

    JSONArray myarray = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ImageView bmImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();


        }
    });

            new GetMyarray().execute();


    }


/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetMyarray extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject getResponse = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                JSONObject pnames=getResponse.getJSONObject("getnames");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + pnames);



                                    myarray = pnames.getJSONArray("pnames");
                Log.d("Listed as: ", "> " + myarray);


                for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = myarray.getJSONObject(i);


                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String viewers=c.getString(TAG_VIEWERS);



                    HashMap<String, String> myarray = new HashMap<String, String>();



                    myarray.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    myarray.put(TAG_VIEWERS, viewers);




                    mylist.add(myarray);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, mylist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_VIEWERS  }, new int[] { R.id.name,R.id.viewers
                        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Google don't have answer?

Comment: I tried lot of answers from google.None of them is working.

Comment: how will you get image ? ..is there different url for different images? or is there a json which have all iamges.?

Comment: But It a very strange that click on `ListView` you are calling your `AsyncTask` and after that set adapter for `ListView` with same??

Comment: For now,i just want one image to be displayed in all ImageViews.That is what i am taking from the url.Later,i am going to use the real json url which contains image ids also

Comment: @Nevaeh..posted an answer..check it

Comment: @Nevaeh..does solution work..?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134) its shown how to load the images in listview from a URL

And just for loading images from a URL there are a lot of SO threads

Answer (score 0):

Please visit

for listview for lazy loading implementations

https://github.com/square/picasso

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
URL url = new URL("your url");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

and

```
public boolean loadImageFromURL(String url, ImageView iv){
try {

URL myUrl = new URL (url);
HttpURLConnection conn =
  (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));

return true;

}  catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }

return false;
}
```

***remember : execute both methods in Asyntask.otherwise it will crash**

Comment: which exception it throws..?

Comment: that simple...its mean you are performing some network operation on main thread..just move the code into asyntask. I have added the text in answer in bold too that put code in asyntask.